# Problem with ENUMERATE: a sort of "NOITEMINDENT"

Tags: enumitem

I have a problem with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}

\title{Enumerate notes}
\author{PUCK}
\date{October 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\Large

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Dimostrazione \arabic*}., leftmargin=3.8cm]
\item bljfaldknfskgjpòfgj pòfkjwpòrkgjpsrogjpsfogjpe fjpsrofgjètohjèogjrèswogjèeot jgpèeogjèeorfgjèsorfgkjèsòorgj kjgèsogkjèsorflgkjèsorgkèspogkjè
\end{enumerate}

I'd like something like so

\noindent\textbf{Dimostrazione 1}. bljfaldknfskgjpòfgj pòfkjwpòrkgjpsrogjpsfogjpe fjpsrofgjètohjèogjrèswogjèeot jgpèeogjèeorfgjèsorfgkjèsòorgj kjgèsogkjèsorflgkjèsorgkèspogkjè

\end{document}
```

How could I obtain the second option using `enumitem-package`? Thank you so much

Comment: Do you need `enumerate` to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}

\title{Enumerate notes}
\author{PUCK}
\date{October 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\Large

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Dimostrazione \arabic*}., leftmargin=3.8cm, wide=0pt]
\item bljfaldknfskgjpòfgj pòfkjwpòrkgjpsrogjpsfogjpe fjpsrofgjètohjèogjrèswogjèeot jgpèeogjèeorfgjèsorfgkjèsòorgj kjgèsogkjèsorflgkjèsorgkèspogkjè
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]